# Network lost when doing big transfers

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, tcpip

normally my wireless network works fine but when I'm doing big (and fast) transfers the network stops working until I reconnect to the Access Point.

Check the following screenshot taken after the network stops:

[image]

The access point works fine as I am connected correctly to it with the phone and the tablet so it is a laptop thing.

The Wifi driver is the latest one:

[image]

Any idea on what could I check?

Thanks.

Comment: rollback to an older driver and look if this fixes it.

Comment: I've tried with several drivers with the same result. More than a solution (as I know its probably a complex problem) I'm looking for ideas of where to look at to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Another thing is that sometimes I get an Unreachable Network message instead of the timeout. It's completely random. And for sure only happens when there are high speed transfers

Comment: may dad also has this ugly WIFI chip and also sometimes issues. I use the inbox driver of Windows 8.1 and here it works ok, but not very well.